# What does this array error mean?

Tags: c, arrays

```
void arrayRound(int id, double baln)
{
    baln[id] = (baln[id]*100) + 0.5;
    int temp = (int) baln[id];
    baln[id] = (double) temp;
    baln[id] = baln[id] / 100;
}
```

The function body is what is giving me error messages. The function is meant to round an array index to the nearest hundredth. I separately passed both the index variable and the array to the function. Here is the error message:

```
Fxns.c:70: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
Fxns.c:70: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
Fxns.c:71: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
Fxns.c:72: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
Fxns.c:73: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
Fxns.c:73: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

My first guess was that I needed to include empty brackets after the baln in the parameter field, but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: You do need to include empty brackets after `baln` in the argument list. Can you show that attempt, please?

Comment: If you look at the function parameters, baln is "neither array nor pointer" but instead listed as a double.  Did you typo or forget to make it a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it right; you do need to include empty brackets after `baln` in the parameter list, like so:

```
void arrayRound(int id, double baln[]);
```

[Here's a full demo.](http://codepad.org/Lfh3rePZ)

Comment: Thanks. The earlier error message with the brackets must've been prompted by some other error.

Comment: @SaiPrasadChimata Since you are new to Stack Overflow, you may be unaware of the ability to mark an answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark outline next to it if it solved your problem. That marks the question as answered, so future viewers need not check whether an answer has been found. If there are several answers solving the problem and none is clearly better than the others - as is the case here, as far as I can see - the choice which answer to accept is arbitrary, but it's common to choose the first, which here would be minitech's. But you need not accept an answer if you don't wish

Comment: @DanielFischer: Actually, you were first by 32 seconds :) So yours should certainly be the accepted answer.

Comment: Your comment was first, I counted that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to treat `baln` of type `double` like an array (using an index.) This will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter should be declared as

```
double *baln
```

a pointer to `double`, or as `double baln[]`, which reads like an array of `double`s, but as a function parameter also denotes a pointer.

```
void arrayRound(int id, double *baln)
{
    baln[id] = (baln[id]*100) + 0.5;
    int temp = (int) baln[id];
    baln[id] = (double) temp;
    baln[id] = baln[id] / 100;
}
```

will compile, but since you don't know what size the memory block `baln` points to is, you may access unallocated memory in this function, if you are not careful.

Answer (score 0):

> error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

```
baln[id]
```

Subscripted Value = baln

Operator`[]`, can only be used either on arrays or pointers. In your case, `baln` is neither. It is of type `double` but not `double[]` or `double*`.

```
int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
a[0] = 10;  // Notice the use of `[]`.This is valid because `a` is an array type.

int b = 10;
int * ptr = &b;
ptr[0] = 99;   // Valid because ptr is a pointer type but cause undefined
               // behaviour for any other index in this example.

*ptr = 99 ; // This is more readable than the earlier case.
```